# ¿Cómo puedo crear una carpeta después de otra en cmd?

Tags: cmd

Tengo archivos por lotes y quisiera crear  primero nombre de todo los archivos en carpetas

Por ejemplo:

si tengo un archivo liquidación que es un pdf primero que cree una carpeta llamada liquidación y luego el archivo dentro liquidacion.pdf y luego que se guarde el archivo en la misma carpeta
quedaría Liquidacion(carpeta)/Liquidacion(archivo pdf)
sobre eso ya tengo el siguiente código.

```
for %i in (*) do mkdir "%~ni"

for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

Pero ahora quisiera crear un carpeta antes que pase dentro de la carpeta así como carpeta documentos ya dependiendo de lo que quiera poner.

Ejemplo:

> Liquidacion(carpeta)/Documentos(carpeta)/Liquidacion(archivo pdf)

Gracias.

Comment: algo como `mkdir -p Liquidacion(carpeta)/Documentos(carpeta)`

Comment: uhm no entiendo amigo